# Customizing Random Forest classifier sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, oop, scikit-learn, random-forest

For personal purposes, I am trying to modify the `Random Forest Classifier` class from `sklearn` to achieve what I am intended. Basically, I am trying that my trees from random forest take some predefined subsample of features and cases so I am modifying the default class.  I am trying to inherit all methods and structure from the original `sklearn` so that the fit method of my customized random forest class can take the original parameters of `sklearn`

For instance, I would like that my customized class was able to take the same parameters as the original fit method:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=2, random_state=None, max_features=None...)


clf = Customized_RF(n_estimators=10, max_depth=2, random_state=None, max_features=None...)
```

but I am having some difficulties doing this, specifically, it seems to be something related to the  `super().__init__` definition where I am getting the following error: `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments`

I am following the github repository as a guideline

[Rf class](https://github.com/kennethriva/myscikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py)

Am I doing something wrong or missing some obvious steps?

This is my approach so far:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

class Customized_RF:
    def __init__(self, n_estimators=10, criterion='gini', max_depth=None, random_state=None):

        super().__init__(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                         n_estimators=n_estimators,
                         estimator_params=("criterion", "max_depth")) # Here's where the error happens

        self.n_estimators = n_estimators

        if random_state is None:
            self.random_state = np.random.RandomState()
        else:
            self.random_state = np.random.RandomState(random_state)

        self.criterion = criterion
        self.max_depth = max_depth

    def fit(self, X, y, max_features=None, cutoff=None, bootstrap_frac=0.8):
        """
        max_features: number of features that each estimator will use,
                      including the fixed features.

        bootstrap_frac: the size of bootstrap sample that each estimator will use.

        cutoff: index feature number from which starting the features subsampling selection. Subsampling for each tree will be done retrieven a random number of features before and after the cutoff. Assuming that the features matrix is not sorted or altered somehow (sparsed).

        """
        self.estimators = []
        self.n_classes  = np.unique(y).shape[0]

        if max_features is None:
            max_features = X.shape[1]  # if max_features is None select all features for every estimator like original

        if cutoff is None:
            cutoff = int(X.shape[1] / 2)  # pick the central index number of the x vector

        print('Cutoff x vector: '.format(cutoff))

        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        n_bs = int(bootstrap_frac*n_samples)  # fraction of samples to be used for every estimator (DT)

        for i in range(self.n_estimators):
                                    replace=False)

            feats_left = self.random_state.choice(cutoff + 1, int(max_features / 2), replace=False)  # inclusive cutoff
            feats_right = self.random_state.choice(range(cutoff + 1, X.shape[1]), int(max_features/2), replace=False)
            # exclusive cutoff

            feats = np.concatenate((feats_left, feats_right)).tolist()

            self.feats_used.append(feats)

            print('Chosen feature indexes for estimator number {0}: {1}'.format(i, feats))

            bs_sample = self.random_state.choice(n_samples, 
                                                 size=n_bs,
                                                 replace=True)

            dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=self.random_state)
            dtc.fit(X[bs_sample][:, feats], y[bs_sample])
            self.estimators.append(dtc)

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        out = np.zeros((X.shape[0], self.n_classes))
        for i in range(self.n_estimators):
            out += self.estimators[i].predict_proba(X[:, self.feats_used[i]])
        return out / self.n_estimators

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.predict_proba(X).argmax(axis=1)

    def score(self, X, y):
        return (self.predict(X) == y).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to derive your own own class from another class, the class definition needs to have a reference to the [base class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), e.g. `class MyClass(BaseClass)`. `super()` then references the base class.

In your case the base class is missing and Python assumes that the generic class `object` is used.

It is not clear from your question if your wanted base class is `DecisionTreeClassifier` or `RandomForestClassifier`. In either case you would need to change your class parameters which are used in `__init__`.

Minor: check for the `replace=False)` line, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: Really helpful, thank you. My base class should be `RandomForestClassifier` I guess, the thing is that I just want you to modify the max_features subsampling, but it is not clear where this modification should be added in the source code. By the way, I can't see the invalid syntax you mentioned in the `replace=False)` line